# Change socklen_t int to uint32_t in sys/socket.h

Tags: c, sockets, android-ndk

I have a conflicting typedef for socklen_t in a library I'm trying to build and an included file from ndk-path/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/socket.h.

The library has `typedef uint32_t socklen_t` but includes sys/socket.h which typedefs it as int. I could make the library use the sys/socket.h version (int) or redefine it in the socket.h header (as below). Which is safer? I tried contacting the author of library but no response. Is changing the definition in socket.h safe?

```
#ifndef _SYS_SOCKET_H_
#define _SYS_SOCKET_H_

#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <linux/socket.h>

__BEGIN_DECLS

#define SOCK_STREAM      1
#define SOCK_DGRAM       2
#define SOCK_RAW         3
#define SOCK_RDM         4
#define SOCK_SEQPACKET   5
#define SOCK_PACKET      10

#ifdef __i386__
# define __socketcall extern __attribute__((__cdecl__))
#else
# define __socketcall extern
#endif

/* BIONIC: second argument to shutdown() */
enum {
    SHUT_RD = 0,        /* no more receptions */
#define SHUT_RD         SHUT_RD
    SHUT_WR,            /* no more transmissions */
#define SHUT_WR         SHUT_WR
    SHUT_RDWR           /* no more receptions or transmissions */
#define SHUT_RDWR       SHUT_RDWR
};


typedef uint32_t socklen_t;

__socketcall int socket(int, int, int);
__socketcall int bind(int, const struct sockaddr *, int);
__socketcall int connect(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
__socketcall int listen(int, int);
__socketcall int accept(int, struct sockaddr *, socklen_t *);
__socketcall int getsockname(int, struct sockaddr *, socklen_t *);
__socketcall int getpeername(int, struct sockaddr *, socklen_t *);
__socketcall int socketpair(int, int, int, int *);
__socketcall int shutdown(int, int);
__socketcall int setsockopt(int, int, int, const void *, socklen_t);
__socketcall int getsockopt(int, int, int, void *, socklen_t *);
__socketcall int sendmsg(int, const struct msghdr *, unsigned int);
__socketcall int recvmsg(int, struct msghdr *, unsigned int);

extern  ssize_t  send(int, const void *, size_t, unsigned int);
extern  ssize_t  recv(int, void *, size_t, unsigned int);

__socketcall ssize_t sendto(int, const void *, size_t, int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
__socketcall ssize_t recvfrom(int, void *, size_t, unsigned int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t *);

#undef __socketcall

__END_DECLS

#endif /* _SYS_SOCKET_H */
```

Comment: You need to match whatever the library thought `socklen_t` was when it was compiled or you will get unresolved symbol linker errors. If you do change something, it'll probably have to be in that library and you will need to re-compile it.

Comment: Are you sure you should be including this file and not just the normal "socket.h"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing system includes is a bad idea, as the rest of the system most certainly relies on what is protoyped/typdefed/declared/definded in there.

So adjust the obviously un-portable library code.